# "Find which coin is fake and which is genuine?"-A coin riddle on parity of numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, parity

> Of $101$ coins, $50$ are counterfeit, and differ from genuine coins in weight by $1$ gram. Peter has a scale in form of balance which shows the difference in weights between the objects placed in each pan. He chooses one coin and wants to find out in one weighing whether it is counterfeit. Can he do this? How?

This question was posed by my teacher. He told me that answer was "Yes, he can find out the nature of coin".
Now I'm stuck on "how he could do that?".
A hint will also help me out as, 'I don't know where to start?'.

Comment: Hint: you have used parity as a tag. Don't weigh the selected coin.

Comment: The counterfeit coins are all one gram heavier? or lighter? or they could be a mixture?

Comment: @Joffan Is the hint still valid given that there are 50 counterfeit coins? ( had a similar thought, but maybe we're thinking different things after all.)

Comment: @rschwieb It is not given which is heavier

Comment: @LoveInvariants But my point is that you think the question means "the counterfeit are all heavier" or "counterfeits are all lighter" and not a mixture, right? That is my question.

Comment: Yeah, they I think the same and they are indeed

Comment: so you put aside one coin and split the remaining coins 50-50. If scales are balanced, the coin that was put aside is bad. Otherwise, it's a good coin.

Comment: It works nicely if there's a mixture as well. Note that this is a " balance which shows the **difference** in weights". So the possible outcomes aren't just "one pan is heavier" vs. "they're equal".

Comment: Your balance gives you very precious information: the DIFFERENCE between the two pans... Look at what would be the difference if the coin is genuine between the 50/50 split of the remaining 100... And if the coin is fake as well...

Comment: Thx Vasya and martigan, now I can try.

Comment: @Vasya  This doesn't work.  If you put 50 fake coins on one side and 50 good on the other, the sides don't balance.  But the same happens if you swap 10 coins and then replace any with the coin in your hand.

Comment: I didn't even notice the "difference" bit before, I thought it was just a lever on a fulcrum :)  nice.

Comment: @B.Goddard It is a question of parity. So if the coin chosen is genuine, then 100 coins, 50 counterfeit and 50 genuine will be left. And their sum will be even which means any two part of coins taken will have an even difference whereas if the coin chosen is counterfeit the difference will be odd.

Comment: @LoveInvariants I know how to do the problem.  My comment is that Vasya's argument doesn't work.  The scales can be unbalanced and you still have a bad coin.

Comment: @B.Goddard True. He had a wrong approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose the fake are $1g$ different, but always on the same side (lighter or heavier).

You have one coin. You keep it on the side.

Split the remaining $100$ coins into two groups of $50$.

If the coin is a good one, you have then $50$ fake ones. Meaning that on the right pan, you will have $50$ coins, $50-x$ being good, $x$ being fakes, and on the left pan, it is the reverse.

So the DIFFERENCE between the two pans is in the form $(50-x)k+x(k+1)-(50-x)(k+1)+xk=2N$, $N \in \mathbb{Z}$, meaning an even number.

If you have it in the form $(2N+1)$, $N \in \mathbb{Z}$, meaning an odd number, then the coin was fake...

Comment: Please remove stars it looks odd.

Comment: In fact it doesn't matter if the fake coins are all heavier or all lighter.  We weren't told that they are.  The parity of the error will still tell whether our selected coin is genuine..

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the coins G for genuine and F for fake.

Imagine instead of 101 coins there were 5 coins: 2 Gs and 3 Fs

Pick one out and there are two options

Option 1. You picked a G so there are 1 G and 3 Fs left

If you split these across the two scales you would have FG/FF or FF/FG and the scales would either read +1 or -1

Option 2. You picked an F so there are 2 Gs and 2 Fs left

If you split these across the two scales you would have FG/FG or FF/GG and the scales would either read 0 or 2.

We can therefore say if we pick one coin and split the remainder: if the scales read + /-1 we picked a genuine coin, if the scales read 0 or 2 we picked a fake one.

Extend this thinking for 7 coins, 9 coins....